# Searching for any combination of strings in data received from BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

So I have the following code:

```
def searchString(toFind, absolute_path) :
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(absolute_path).read())
    text = soup.get_text()
    if toFind in text :
            return True
    return False
```

Now say that the string is `"aBc"`. The code that I have will return `True` only if `toFind` exactly matches a string in `text`. Is there a way that I can find out if any combination of `"aBc"` is present in `text`?

Comment: can you give example like input and expected result

Comment: Say I am seraching for "abc" and the text is " Abc def ghi". Then it should return True. However if the text is "abc" and the text is "ab cde" is should return false

Comment: You mean toFind is 'abc' and text is 'ab cde', then it should return False?

Comment: your "any combination of aBc" is confusing. i think what you are trying to achieve can be done by `toFind.lower()`

Comment: What would be faster? converting the string to lower case and then comparing or using regular expressions?

Answer (score 1):

To do case insensitive search, code will look like this:

```
def searchString(toFind, absolute_path) :
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(absolute_path).read())
    text = soup.get_text()
    if toFind.lower() in text.lower():
            return True
    return False
```